# Can a core i5 lynnfield handle burning multiple bluray m-discs at once?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, dvd, burning

I'm trying to repurpose my old 2010 era mobo and cpu and turn it into a burning machine with 5 or 6 5.25 bays, that's the only good use I could think of for it other than to relearn how to build a rig because I forgot. It's not really worth selling the parts. So it's that or the recycling depot.

It has a core i5 lga 1156, I don't know the exact chip it's in a box somewhere, but it's not the best lga 1156, anyway, would it be powerful enough to burn to multiple writers at once? (would any lga 1156?) the mobo supports 6x sata, that's all I want it to do, burn m-discs slowly, 750w power supply, won't put a gpu, nothing else to clutter up the case.

Comment: It probably depends a lot more on the speed of your blu-ray burners and the device the data is being copied from than your processor.

Comment: I see, makes sense, it has all this on the mobo                                                                                          2 x PCIe 2.0 x16 (single at x16 or dual at x8/x8 mode)
1 x PCI Express 2.0 x16 slots (at x4 mode, 2.5GT/s)
2 x PCI Express 2.0 x1 (2.5GT/s)
2 x PCI           -  but will be hard to find those ancient drives, otherwise it's 3gbps sata 2 I think it supports, the discs will be burning slow, just archiving.

Comment: Donate it to charity, lots of school kids are trying to do home schooling without a computer at the moment.